# Exporting nested JSON to Excel in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying to export nested json to excel with specific format in react. I found few solution with XLSX which print only root node but I would also like to print nested nodes. Here is my JSON

```
[
   {
      "Root":"00000",
      "RootId":"b597b7be58b0",
      "Index":0,
      "Child":[
         {
            "ChildId":"48bb0b4be689",
            "Name":"Dimension",
            "Index":0,
            "SubChild0":[
               {
                  "SubChildId":"6b620696cf35",
                  "Label":"Sample 2",
                  "Index":1
               },
               {
                  "SubChildId1":"f6b620696cf38",
                  "Label":"Sample 2",
                  "Index":2
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "ChildId-01":"dcf70d3a-60b3-4b8c-8740-48bb0b4be689",
            "Name":"Weight",
            "Index":0,
            "SubChild1":[
               {
                  "SubChildId":"f42d99f5-37c5-4ea3-8425-6b620696cf35",
                  "Label":"Sample 2",
                  "Index":1
               },
               {
                  "SubChildId1":"f42d99f5-37c5-4ea3-8425-6b620696cf35",
                  "Label":"Sample 2",
                  "Index":2
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and I would like to print in excel something like below format

[image]

Comment: Looking for  similar solution

Comment: I don't believe you will find a solution that will work without processing the data first. If your child data could be placed below instead of to the right, it would also make it a little easier.

Comment: @NickSlash Thanks for your reply. I am fine with solution you suggested. Do you have some idea regarding  library which could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I've never used any libraries that would help with your problem so cannot suggest any.

Your source data can be processed using javascript.

Your data almost fits a regular nested list with children, so creating a recursive function to process the data into something that can be interpreted as a CSV shouldn't be too difficult.

Your data has different tags so is a little more complicated.

The example below wont work for your data as-is. But it might give you an idea of where to start?

```
// source data with uniform keys in child objects
let data = [ 
    {
        "name": "root1",
        "label": "root label",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "root1child1",
                "label": "root1 child1 label",
                "children": [
                    { 
                        "name": "root1child1subchild1",
                        "label": "root1 child1 subchild1 label"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "root1child1subchild2",
                        "label": "root1 child1 subchild2 label"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "root1child2",
                "label": "my label",
                "children": [
                    { 
                        "name": "root1child2subchild1",
                        "label": "root1 child2 subchild1 label"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "root1child2subchild2",
                        "label": "root1 child2 subchild2 label"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
 ]

let result = []

function process(node,padding) {
for (let i = 0, l = node.length; i<l; i++) {
    result.push(Array(padding).concat("name", node[i].name))
    result.push(Array(padding).concat("label", node[i].label))
    if (node[i].children) {
        // process the child node and pad the result to the right
        process(node[i].children,++padding)
    }
    // reset padding and continue with next
    --padding
}
}
// start processing the data
process(data,0)
// print the result as a table to the console
console.table(result)
```